# BeautifulSoup: Merge all p elements into one string?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I currently use following Python code excerpt to get all

elements of a webpage:

```
def scraping(url, html):
    data = {}
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")

    data["news"] = []

    page = soup.find("div", {"class":"container_news"}).findAll('p')
    page_text = ''

    for p in page:
        page_text += ''.join(p.findAll(text = True))
        data["news"].append(page_text)
    print(page_text)

    return data
```

However, the output of `page_text` looks like:

```
"['New news on the internet. ', 'Here is some text. ', ""Here is some other."", ""And then there are other variations \n\nLooks like there are some non-text elements. \n\xa0""]" ...
```

Is it possible to get the content cleaner and merge the lists into one string? BeautifulSoup solutions would be preferred over regex variants.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure of the significance of maintaining `data["news"]`, but this can be done in a single line:

```
page_text = ' '.join(e.text for p in page for e in p.findAll(text=True))
```

Instead of `' '` you can use whatever string you want as delimiter.

Otherwise

```
page_text = []

for p in page:
    page_text.extend(e.text for e in p.findAll(text=True))
    data["news"].append(page_text)

print(' '.join(page_text))
```